# Should domain models call infrastructure interfaces?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, onion-architecture

is the following good design and allowable in onion architecture and domain driven design?

say you have an "Order" domain class like so

```
class Order
{
  INotificationService _notificationService;
  ICartRepository _cartRepository;

   void Checkout(Cart cart, bool notifyCustomer)
   {
         _cartRepository.Save(cart);
         if (notifyCustomer)
         {
            _notificationService.sendnotification();
         }
   }
}
```

Is it good or bad design to have the domain model call interfaces of infrastructure?( in this case, notificationservice and CartRepository)

Comment: Are you sure that calling the customer notification is a concern of your Order?  This rather seems to be an application level concern to me.  What about future actions that need to be done when a customer checks out, such as giving credit for future sales, notify your internal statistics database, other bookkeeping, etc?  Are you always going to modify your Order class?  For the SPR principles, I suggest to raise a domain event as in the answers below and handle the event in independent observers.

Answer (score 2):

Your design will be OK only if both `INotificationService` and `ICartRepository` interfaces are defined within your `Domain` (`Core`) layer **and** if they're bound at runtime with the right implementation by your `Dependency Resolution` layer (the outermost layer of your Onion architecture).

Remember that in an Onion architecture, your `Domain` layer cannot reference any libraries.

`ICartRepository` implementation will obviously be done in your `Infrastucture` layer as it will surely be tied to your Data Access layer technology.
If your `INotificationService` implementation needs to talk to an external service, then it goes to `Infrasrtructure` as well. But if it is part of your business then it's implementation could be in the `Domain` layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think INotificationService is a domain concept rather than infrastructure service. We could model this as a DomainEvent telling "the customer about the cart is saved".

What about moving the INotificationService to the domain layer and rename it as "CartDomainEvents".

```
CartDomainEvents.raise(CartSavedEvent(...));
```

In general case, Calling infrastructure components introduces bidirectional dependencies which  is usually not a good design.

Comment: `"Calling infrastructure components introduces bidirectional dependencies which is usually not a good design"`. You're definitely right, but remember that, in an Onion Architecture, all dependencies are toward the center! So bidirectional dependencies should not be allowed anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Repository layer are exist for each aggregate of the domain,repository is on top of domain, you can have repository base interfaces on your domain who they live in infrastructure but you can not see the repository implementations in your model(it's not correct).
there are some basic interfaces such as UnitOfWrok, Repository, Specificationm authentication and ... in your infrastructure accessible in all layers. I recommend to take a look at aghata store front written in .net to see a real implementation project https://github.com/elbandit/Asp-Net-Design-Patterns-CQRS

Answer (score 0):

repository belong to infrastructure layer 
also it would be better to use Icart interface

```
void Checkout(ICart cart, bool notifyCustomer)
```

to reduce coupling.